# Image quality degraded after scaling

Tags: c#, image-processing

I am resizing a bitmap image. The result is a quality degraded picture.
I am using `System.Graphics` for scaling.

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(image,new Rectangle(10, 250, (int)(0.6 * width), (int)(0.6 * height)), 0, 0,    width, height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set your interpolation mode to bicubic interpolation before drawing the image :

```
e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
```

This mode produces the highest quality transformed images.

Comment: another problem arises now @Sam, half of the pixel is lost on the sides of the image. does this have anything to do with the selected interpolation mode ?

Comment: check the PixelOffsetMode. e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode

Comment: setting the PixelOffsetMode to half worked out but why ? what does that means ?

Comment: check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.pixeloffsetmode(v=vs.110).aspx. "Half" Specifies that pixels are offset by -.5 units, both horizontally and vertically, for high speed antialiasing.